# PIVOT returns only one row

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I've been creating a pivot that turns the string into a table, and fortunately it did. But it only contains one row (the first record in the table).

Here's the code:

```
SELECT 
    COL1,COL2,COL3.... etc.
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        LEFT(CA.val,CHARINDEX('=',CA.val)-1) ColumnName,
        SUBSTRING(CA.val,CHARINDEX('=',CA.val)+1,100) Value
    FROM (MYTABLE)
    CROSS APPLY (MYFUNCTION)(MYTABLECOLUMNNAME,'|') CA
) PD
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value)
    FOR ColumnName IN (COL1,COL2,COL3.... etc.)
) AS PT
```

The output for the `SELECT` statement only (without Putting it in the `PIVOT`) :

```
ColumnName  Value
------------------------
Name        Value1
Age         Value2
Name        DiffValue
Age         DiffValue2
```

The output of `PIVOT` table

```
Name    AGE
Value1  Value2
```

So basically the pivot table only prints the first record and bypass the other row. Is it because it has the same column name?

I want the output to be like this:

```
Name        AGE
------------------------
Value1      Value2 
DiffValue   DiffValue2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with the `PIVOT` syntax, but here is an alternative way to pivot your data using conditional aggregation:

```
WITH Tbl(ColumnName, Value) AS(
    SELECT 'Name', 'Value1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Age', 'Value2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Name', 'DiffValue' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Age', 'DiffValue2' 
),
CteRn AS(
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColumnName ORDER BY Value)
    FROM Tbl
)
SELECT
    Name = MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 'Name' THEN Value END),
    Age  = MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 'Age' THEN Value END)
FROM CteRn
GROUP BY Rn
```

The bottomline here is, you need to add `ROW_NUMBER` to add an id to your data and then use that id in the `GROUP BY`.

---

Here is my attempt at `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH Tbl(ColumnName, Value) AS(
    SELECT 'Name', 'Value1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Age', 'Value2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Name', 'DiffValue' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Age', 'DiffValue2' 
),
CteRn AS(
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColumnName ORDER BY Value)
    FROM Tbl
)
SELECT
    [Name], [Age]
FROM CteRn r
PIVOT(
    MAX(Value)
    FOR ColumnName IN([Name], [Age])
)p
```

*The cte `TBL` here is the output of your `SELECT` query.*

Comment: So there's really no way to put all the rows in the pivot without having a key? id? or so? That's what I've been thinking putting some ID, but I thought there's a way without id or etc. Anyway , Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I believe you need an `UNPIVOT`-ed column, in this case the `Rn` to achieve your desired result. Again, I'm not really familiar with `PIVOT`. But in the case of the conditional aggregation, you surely need that unique id.